# Is it possible to run SVN server on LAMP? (e.g. GoDaddy shared hosting account)

Tags: svn, cgi, lamp, shared-hosting, adapter

I have a shared-hosting account at GoDaddy, which includes [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) (Linux, Apache HTTP Server, MySQL, and PHP). I really like SVN as my source control, and I thought "hey, maybe it's possible to have my own SVN server hosted in my GoDaddy account!"

So, is it possible? Is there a "bridge" that enables SVN on LAMP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually no. Subversion needs binaries installed, and tight integration with the underlying system (e.g. with Apache to serve multiple repositories) to work well.

Comment: Side note: Being based in Israel, it's probably not relevant for you, but I did some research a while back about hosted Subversion and came across this german company: http://www.inetrobots.com/hosting-solutions.html Their SVN packages (paired with hosting) are some of the most affordable I've seen, even internationally. I have no personal experience with them - my plans changed and I didn't need hosted SVN after all, but had I needed it, I would have tried them.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the host.  DreamHost allows you to set up Subversion on a shared hosting account, and I've been using them successfully for a while.

Comment: mediatemple has svn on grid accounts as well.. although you have to use svn+ssh for access.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about SVN, but you can definitely set up a Git repository without needing to install Git on the remote machine.  And Git > SVN :-).  It's a bit complicated though.

**Edit**:  I tried to find a walkthrough to do this but failed as yet.  But the basic steps are pretty simple (this is all from memory from a year or two back though):

1. Initialize a bare git repo on your local machine.  This will act as the origin to the only person who would be able to push to the remote: you.
2. Create a trigger that copies the contents of that directory to the remote server (FTP, rsync: whatever's available to you) on commits, etc.
3. For you, clone the origin located on your local machine so that somebody can push to it.  For all others, they should clone the directory on the remote server as if it were an "authentic" git repository.
4. Configure access rights accordingly, however you can.

It's not a "true" Git repository I suppose, but I've used it before and it works for the purposes I used it for.

The [Git User's Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#setting-up-a-public-repository) goes through part of the steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed cgi access, and you can install binaries (or your host has svn installed) then yes, you can set up a subversion repository on your site.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual private server would be more adequate for hosting an SVN repo.

Comment: Yes, but also more administrative hassle - not everybody wants that.

Comment: Right. I guess for a new hosting, Dreamhost is the best choice so far.

Answer (score 0):

As well you can consider a free private svn hosting services. Check [Free Online Private SVN repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories)